# Can the iOS simulator create a Game Center match with a device?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator, game-center, gamekit

I have two iTunes Connect test users. One logged in my game using an iPhone 5 device (iOS 7), and another in the iOS 7 simulator.

I started a matchmaking search, but they don't seem to react and keep on searching for players.

I have read that the simulator can't handle matchmaking invitations, but does that include normal random matchmaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. At least with iOS 7.

I am not sure why did it not work before. However, it is possible that it begun working after I deleted the applications in both the device and simulator, cleaning and reinstalling.

I am now successfully able to start a match between the simulator and device. Data transfer works fine.

> I have read that the simulator can't handle matchmaking invitations,
>   but does that include normal random matchmaking?

The simulator can do normal random matchmaking alright. It indeed can't handle matchmaking invitations, since it isn't a real device I suppose that push notifications like these don't work.